# Create new element using jquery draggable/droppable and sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

What I am trying to do is create a Card Sorting script. Basically, you have a listing of "cards" that you are then supposed to sort into any number of "stacks" (lists). I am using the jQuery-UI sortable plugin and am able to connect lists to drag between them. The issue I am facing is that I cannot figure out a way to make it check to see if the card is hovering over blank space or an existing list, and if the former, when I drop it, create a new list.

I have tried using draggable/droppable so that the card is not initially confined to sortables, but I still cannot get it to recognize where the card is. I'm also thinking that draggable/droppable will not be what I need because then I cannot move the card from a sortable back to original listing (draggable).

Ultimately, I'll be using jQuery's ajax ability to save the results of the sorting, but I can't do that until I can get it to create new lists.

Does anyone have any experience in doing something like this? Any help would be great!

Comment: Perhaps prepare a jsfiddle of what you have so far?  When asking more complex questions, it often takes a fair amount of time to code an example from scratch for the people answering the question.

Comment: That's a neat tool. Here's what I came up with. Forgive the ugliness, and note that I've tried other things more than I have there now. Currently, the initial list is a sortable and have it able to add a new "stack" by clicking the + link that is showing under the original list, and items from the original list can move between it and the created sortables. http://jsfiddle.net/Em8gn/6/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry for the late response, but was working on it and didn't notice the other answer.

My variation does something pretty comparable to Goran's. http://jsfiddle.net/fordlover49/rxVPq/

Note that you'd need to add the titles, and everything else according to what you're wanting still, but it accomplishes the basic goal, while keeping the original items, and only have one set of options for the sortable lists..

While Goran's solution appears to work, I would caution you that the method he's using to move the objects is dangerous and incorrect.  If you had any event binders on the items that's moving to the new list, they will be lost because he's removed the old items that you had the event bindings to from the DOM.

Comment: That's a good point. I'll take a look at your solution as well to see which one works best. Thanks to you to for working on this to help me out. I'll upvote you and if I end up using your implementation instead of the other one I'll set this one to the solution.

Comment: Well yours works well also and since it has the added benefit of not losing event bindings, I'll mark this as the solution. Thanks again (both of you).

Answer (score 0):

Although I couldn't figure out how to get the event for creating a new stack if dragged onto an empty part of the screen, the best I could do is by dragging cards onto a `new` area.

See the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bzpkg/7/).

The code allows you to drags cards from the deck to either an existing stack or a new stack, and also back to the deck if need be. It also removes stacks (but not the deck) if left empty after an item being dragged to a new location.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's definitely a possibility for how to do this Thanks for taking the time to do it. I'll see if I can implement your solution into what I have and I'll let you know how it works.

Comment: I'm marking this as solved. I have been able to implement your solution to create new "stacks" on the fly. Even though it's not exactly how I envisioned it, it works great. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This approach is very dangerous as you're removing the original item from the DOM and recreating it.  By doing it this way, you lose any of the event bindings that might have previously existed with that element.

Comment: @PriorityMark - Fixed, was only a single line of code. Late-night coding evidently isn't my forte.

Comment: @GoranMottram I know the feeling on that one ;).